# Rails 3 -> Could not find generator surveyor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, surveyor-gem

Hey!
https://github.com/breakpointer/ trying to use,
When i trying to write rails generate surveyor
i receive this: COuld not find generator surveyor!

could you help me?

using rails 3, ruby 1.8.7

Comment: have you done bundle install already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using the rails3 branch?

I was getting the same exception as you but fixed it by having the following in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'surveyor', :git => 'git://github.com/breakpointer/surveyor.git', :branch => 'rails3'
gem 'formtastic'
```

Comment: theres a note on github saying "The main branch is at NUBIC/Surveyor. This is no longer the active development branch!"

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble with my installation on Rail 3.0.9

```
gem 'surveyor', :git => 'https://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor.git', :branch => 'rails3'
gem 'formtastic'
```

Gave my formtastic 2.0.0 resulting in this error -> uninitialized constant Formtastic::SemanticFormHelper

Found a blog post about upgrading...but that will be another day :-)
http://richardhulse.blogspot.com/2011/06/upgrading-to-formtastic-20.html

I then downgraded to 1.2.4 and was able to generate surveyor

```
gem 'surveyor', :git => 'https://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor.git', :branch => 'rails3'
gem 'formtastic', '~> 1.2.4'
```

Answer (score 1):

theres a note on github saying "The main branch is at NUBIC/Surveyor. This is no longer the active development branch!" so you might want to use

```
gem 'surveyor', :git => 'git://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor.git', :branch => 'rails3'
gem 'formtastic'
```

instead.

Also, the actual command to generate the stuff is

```
rails generate surveyor:install
```